# Pytorch model forward speed is lowered while using torch.multiprocessing

Tags: multiprocessing, pytorch, torch

I am new to pytorch and recently I found the model forward speed is lowered using torch.multiprocessing when I running the code in [Pytorch Documentation Multiprocessing Best Practice](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.2.0/notes/multiprocessing.html#best-practices-and-tips) and [pytorch example of mnist_hogwild](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/mnist_hogwild).

When I set the num_processes as 1, the forward time is about 5ms. But the forward time increased to 10ms when num_processes = 2 and 16-30ms when num_processes = 4

[forward time when num_process = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU7zc.png)

[forward time when num_process = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vUjG.png)

[forward time when num_process = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFEa2.png)

At first I thought it was because the model was shared only with parameters and there is conflicts in computing resources. So I changed the code and create model instances inside the subprocesses. There are the test results below.

[forward time when num_process = 1 and models are independent in subprocesses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTLYo.png)

[forward time when num_process = 2 and models are independent in subprocesses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enl8U.png)

[forward time when num_process = 4 and models are independent in subprocesses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNHMM.png)

The forward speed of model is lowered though models are indepedent.

What's going on there?

Comment: ps. The models are all running in cpu, no gpu is used.